# React Native: TextInput with state and AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

When typing on the keyboard I was seeing some warnings about the input being ahead of the JS code..

> Native TextInput(react native is awesome) is 4 events ahead of JS - try to make your JS faster.

So added the `debounce` and got this to "work":

```
...
import { debounce } from 'lodash'
...
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data,
      indexRef: data.reduce((result, item, index) => {
        result[item.title] = index
        return result
      }, {}),
      ready: false,
    }

    this.updatePitch = this.updatePitch.bind(this)
    this.saveLocally = debounce(this.saveLocally, 300).bind(this)
  }
  ...
  updatePitch(id, text) {
    // Copy the data
    let data = [...this.state.data]
    const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id == id)
    data[index].pitch = text
    // Update the state
    this.setState({ data }, this.saveLocally(data))
  }

  saveLocally(data) {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))
      this.forceUpdate()
    } catch (error) {
      // Well..
    }
  }

  render() {
  ...
```

BTW: I'm doing some "prop drilling" for now - but planning to do use the [Context API (react 16.3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLJN4JfniH4)

The warning seems to have gone by adding `debounce` (1).. But I'm seeing some strange issues - particularly on the `iPhone 8 plus` simulator (not seeing the same on iPhone 6 simulator or Android device)

Issues observed:

- `TextInput` don't expand - it just add scolling (expands on iPhone 6 and Android device)
- Some layout issues in the `FlatList` - seems like it has problems finding correct height of list elements..

## What is the best practice for fast JS code and saving to both `state` and `AsyncStorage`?

(1) One other way than using `debounce` could be to use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://youtu.be/yaZzJ37Qb0U?t=10m51s) and add some sort of timer pushing the state to the parent component after some period of time.. But wasn't sure that this would make the JS code faster. So didn't try it.

### UPDATE (again)

[image: Open Source]

I open sourced the entire code since it is too hard to give all the needed information in a SO post when the code is so nested.

The entire code is here:
https://github.com/Norfeldt/LionFood_FrontEnd

(I know that my code might seem messy, but I'm still learning..)

I don't expect people to go in and fix my code with PR (even though it would be awesome) but just give me some code guidance on how to proper deal with `state` and `AsyncStorage` for `TextInput`.

I know I have some style issues - would love to fix them, but also comply with SO and keep it on topic.

### Update II

I removed `forceUpdate` and replaced `FadeImage` with just vanilla react native `Image`.

but I'm still seeing some weird issues

[image: Weird behavior]

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  StatusBar,
  ImageBackground,
  AsyncStorage,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

import Section from './Section'
import ButtonContact from './ButtonContact'

import { data } from '../data.json'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data,
      indexRef: data.reduce((result, item, index) => {
        result[item.title] = index
        return result
      }, {}),
      ready: false,
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide()
    try {
      let BusinessPlan = await AsyncStorage.getItem('BusinessPlan')
      if (BusinessPlan !== null) {
        // We have data!!
        let data = JSON.parse(BusinessPlan)
        data = this.state.data.map(item => {
          const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id == item.id)
          const pitch = index >= 0 ? data[index].pitch : ''
          return { ...item, pitch }
        })
        this.setState({ data, ready: true })
      } else {
        this.setState({ ready: true })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
    }
  }

  updatePitch = (id, text) => {
    // Copy the data
    let data = [...this.state.data]
    const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id == id)
    data[index].pitch = text
    // Update the state
    this.setState({ data }, this.saveLocally(data))
  }

  saveLocally = data => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('BusinessPlan', JSON.stringify(data))
    } catch (error) {
      // Well..
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LinearGradient
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        start={{ x: 0.0, y: 0.25 }}
        end={{ x: 0.5, y: 1.0 }}
        colors={['#000000', '#808080', '#000000']}
      >
        <StatusBar
          barStyle={'light-content'}
          backgroundColor={Platform.OS == 'iOS' ? 'transparent' : 'black'}
        />
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ImageBackground
            source={require('../images/BackgroundImage.png')}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
            resizeMode={'cover'}
          >
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.data}
              initialNumToRender="16"
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Section
                  id={item.id}
                  title={item.title}
                  pitch={item.pitch}
                  updatePitch={debounce(this.updatePitch, 1000)}
                  questions={item.questions}
                  ready={this.state.ready}
                />
              )}
              ListFooterComponent={<ButtonContact />}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: '#000',
                borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
              }}
            />
          </ImageBackground>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </LinearGradient>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionHeader: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
})
```

(I also updated my git repo)

### Update III

It seems that the setup I have for `state` and `AsyncStorage` works fine with a `debounce`. The issues I was seeing was because I'm draining the CPU (next step to fix).

Comment: You shouldn't need debounce for `TextInput`. Why did you call `this.forceUpdate()`? Try removing that and debounce.

Comment: @riwu I force update it since I was experiencing some layout issues with either the textinput or flatlist (can't recall)

Comment: Then you should try to fix those layout issues. Calling `this.forceUpdate()` here is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Can you please add the structure of your `data`? Better data structure can lead to faster updates.

Comment: @bennygenel I have updated my question

Comment: @riwu that's easier said than done..

Comment: What I'm saying is you are trying to fix the wrong problem. Remove `forceUpdate` and update your question with the resulting layout issues. Also you are mutating the state with `data[index].pitch = text` as you only created a shallow copy. Try `data[index] = { ...data[index], pitch: text }`.

Comment: I agree with @riwu. Please try to remove `forceUpdate` and `debounce`. Just update directly to your state

Comment: In my experience I have `NEVER` faced a case/problem where I would need to use `forceUpdate` and that should be avoided. Also don't add `async` bind directly into React life-cycle method this case `DidMount`, just keep them synchronous and add helper methods instead which you could use as async. You are basically breaking React's natural behaviour when doing these.

Comment: @JimiPajala I have made an update so you can see more code much more clear and perhaps tell me how to do - instead of not to do :-)

Comment: @riwu I have made an update so you can see more code much more clear and perhaps tell me how to do - instead of not to do :-)

Comment: @anhtu I have made an update so you can see more code much more clear and perhaps tell me how to do - instead of not to do :-)

Comment: @bennygenel I have made an update so you can see more code much more clear and perhaps tell me how to do - instead of not to do :-)

Comment: @Norfeldt I am telling you what not to do, because I expect you to fix these issues before looking more deeply into source of issue. Most of your issues might be caused be these feature miss use cases which might break React's natural behaviour.

Comment: @JimiPajala sorry I didn't mean it like that.

Comment: @Norfeldt I updated my answer.pls check

Comment: @JimiPajala I updated the code to not use `forceUpdate` but it's still going crazy.

Comment: @riwu I updated the code to not use `forceUpdate` but it's still going crazy.

Comment: @bennygenel I updated the code to not use `forceUpdate` but it's still going crazy.

Comment: you did not explain what the "weird issues" are. Also try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The process of removing code bit by bit until the problem disappear also help you to pinpoint exactly what code is causing the issue.

Comment: @riwu I did attach a gif of the weird issues - the image is moving (which it should not) and the speech bubble goes behind the card (which it should not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code:

- "I'm seeing some strange issues - particularly on the iPhone 8 plus
  simulator (not seeing the same on iPhone 6 simulator or Android
  device)" ==> I confirmed this
- The app takes about 100% CPU.

After a while trying I figured out:

- "I'm seeing some strange issues - particularly on the iPhone 8 plus
  simulator (not seeing the same on iPhone 6 simulator or Android
  device)" ==> doesn't right, just wait a little `TextInput` will expand.
- There are nothing wrong with state and AsyncStorage. I didn't get any warning.

The root issue is the animation in `FadeImage` :

- The app render many `Carousel`, and each `Carousel` has `AngleInvestor`, and `FadeImage`. The problem is `FadeImage`
- `FadeImage` run `Animated` with duration 1000 => **CPU is overloaded**

  ==> That why `TextInput` add scroll then take a long time to expand, and `FlatList` look like has problem, but not. They are just slowly updated.

Solution:

- Try to comment `FadeImage`, you will see the problem gone away.
- Don't start so many animations as the same time. Just start if it appears (Ex: the first card in `Carousel` )

**UPDATE**

I got your problem: **typing fastly cause `setState` call so many times**.
You use can `debounce` for this situation:

In App.js

```
render() {
    console.log('render app.js')
    ...
                <Section
                  id={item.id}
                  title={item.title}
                  pitch={item.pitch}
                  updatePitch={debounce(this.updatePitch, 1000)} // the key is here
                  questions={item.questions}
                  ready={this.state.ready}
                />
```

You can change the delay and watch the console log to see more. As I tried, delay about 500 can stop the warning.

P/s: You should try to remove `forceUpdate`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time looking at my code and trying to help me out - I really appreciate it! I tried changing the `FadeImage` to just a regular `Image` and it's still behaving really weird.. But your right it seems to be choking on some big loading.

Comment: I added an image of the weird behavior. I find it really hard to debug and not sure what to ask for help about on SO.

Comment: @Norfeldt I updated my answer. Maybe can solve your problem.

Comment: Once again - thank you so much for you time. I forgot to remove `forceUpdate` in my first attempt. Now I have removed it (see **Update II** in my post) and did what you suggested. But it's still choking..

Comment: @Norfeldt using `updatePitch={debounce(this.updatePitch, 1000)}` still choking? As your image?

Comment: Try with 1 card first. Remove data, just keep 1 card. Then `debounce` with 1000

Comment: By "choking" I mean that I can see that is working really and and updating little by little all the time. An the updates are not correct https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkXAj.gif

Comment: @Norfeldt with 1 card still choking?

Comment: Sorry, I not able to test it right now - but later today

Comment: Having just 1 deck of cards seems to work just fine and the `debounce` does the job perfectly.

Comment: Thank for accepted the answer. I think there are so many cards. So the app is heavy for the device. With many cards, you can try to type and wait. They will layout correctly. It takes time. So now, the problem is optimizing the rendering objects. It is another issue.

Comment: Thank you for your helping me out finding the issue. I found that it's because I put the `Carousel`s within a `FlatList`